# Checking if an input file has been selected?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on a website, where you are able to upload a file:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="form-control" />
```

I then have a button which you can press to upload the selected file:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Upload CV</button>
```

Here I would like the button to be clickable *ONLY* if a file has been selected. Is this possible using JS, and how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am pretty new to JS, but I thought maybe it was possible to check, when the button is pressed, if a file was selected - but that's not quite what I am looking to achieve. I haven't tried anything yet since I am quite lost on how to do it.

Comment: Look at HTML5 Form Validation. Built in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JQuery as FullOfQuestions said, but it would be also good to verify that the file was selected before executing button code!

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="myFile"/>

<!--Add disabled attribute to the button so that is appears disabled at page load-->
<button id="myBtn" type="submit" disabled>Upload CV</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            //when input's value changes
            $("#myFile").change(function () {
                if($(this).val())
                {
                    $("#myBtn").prop("disabled", false);
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#myBtn").prop("disabled", true);
                }
            });

            //when button is clicked
            $("#myBtn").click(function () {
                if($("#myFile").val())
                {
                    console.log("file selected");
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

Comment: That works like a charm, and after the Postback, the button gets dsiabled once again :D Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $('input:file').change(
        function(){
            if ($(this).val()) {
                $('input:submit').attr('disabled',false);
                // or, as has been pointed out elsewhere:
                // $('input:submit').removeAttr('disabled'); 
            } 
        }
        );
});
```

Add disabled attribute in button tag.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! joalcego said, this works very well! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with native JS below. The button is enabled when a file has been selected, but if a file has not been selected, the button is disabled.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button[type=submit]');

button.disabled = true;

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', function () {
  if (this.value.length > 0) {
    button.disabled = false;
  } else {
    button.disabled = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="form-control" />

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Upload CV</button>
```